# How to start Teamviewer or any program before login

Tags: unity, login, scripts, vnc, teamviewer

Teamviewer is a remote desktop application, it doesn't have to be this one, I'd be interested to know the following for any remote desktop application like VNC or RDP.

I added a "Startup script" to run Teamviewer automatically but it only runs when I log in.

Is there a way to run such a program before any log in, so that the login can be done remotely?

Many thanks!

Comment: Have you tried SSH instead?.

Comment: SSHD is running as a system service and it is working, you can even forward the windows with:
ssh -X user@host
but this is not a not a remote desktop, you cannot control remotely the mouse of the system and see what is shown on the computer.
Any idea?
You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Teamviewer version 8 (which just came out) has the option to run as daemon which makes it start automatically when Ubuntu is booting (see the 'Special note for our Linux users' on [the Teamviewer site](https://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/currentversion.aspx).

Answer (score -1):

Normally, such programs are started through scripts in /etc/init.d/, to which links point from /etc/rcX.d/ directories. However, I bet that somewhere in Teamviewer manuals there is a description how to add a teamviewer service for good :)

Comment: This program needs to capture the user interface and interaction.
How can you install any remote desktop to run before the user login?